# Python OpenCV 3.1.0 Error: Image data can not convert to float when I try to use Sobel Operator

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, sobel

I am using an example shown here: http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d5/d0f/tutorial_py_gradients.html

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('dave.jpg',0)

laplacian = cv2.Laplacian(img,cv2.CV_64F)
sobelx = cv2.Sobel(img,cv2.CV_64F,1,0,ksize=5)
sobely = cv2.Sobel(img,cv2.CV_64F,0,1,ksize=5)

plt.subplot(2,2,1),plt.imshow(img,cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Original'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(2,2,2),plt.imshow(laplacian,cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Laplacian'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(2,2,3),plt.imshow(sobelx,cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Sobel X'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(2,2,4),plt.imshow(sobely,cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Sobel Y'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])

plt.show()
```

to get started working with a Sobel Operator on images in python. But when I run it it throws the error: TypeError: Image data can not convert to float.

Comment: Please post the whole error traceback to figure out where the error actually happened, Also make that your image is properly loaded after `img = cv2.imread('dave.jpg',0)` by verifying `print img.shape`